# PHP PDO statement returns incorrect row count with SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount, prepared-statement

Why does this portion of code return `true` even when it shouldn't be?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :username LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
return ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) ? true : false;
```

If I enter a username in a field that has already been registered, it returns true which then outputs:

```
That username has already been taken!
```

But if I enter a username that **hasn't** been registered, it still returns true and outputs the line above. I'm unsure why this is and how it can be fixed.

I know that the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) states that `rowCount()` has some issues with `SELECT` queries, but I can't find a workaround for this that returns the number of rows affected by a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because COUNT() will always return 1 row, although its value may be 0.

You can do a SELECT TRUE instead:

```
SELECT TRUE FROM `users` WHERE `username`= :username LIMIT 1
```

Or you can check if the value is greater than 0:

```
return ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0);
```

BTW - the "? true : false" part is redundant; having the boolean condition by itself does just that.

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I'd like to know more about SELECT TRUE. Is there any documentation on it? I've tried searching but can't find anything.

Comment: it's no different than executing `select 1` or `select 'blahblahblah' or `select 1+1`. You don't HAVE to select from a table, you can select fixed text which simply gets returned (or returns `2` in the case of `1+1`). However, some DBs (like oracle) require you to select form a special pseudo-table named 'dual' for such queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the number of result rows. As your query returns always exactly one result row, `rowCount()` returns 1. The one result row will contain the count, e.g. 0 or 1 in with your query.

You need to check that count value in the result-row or change your query to not return any rows in case the user does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple without binding:

```
$res = $dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS total FROM `users` WHERE `username`= "'.$username.'" ')->fetch();

return ($res['total'] == 1) ? true : false;
```